# Adding opengl to core-image-base in yocto

Tags: opengl, raspberry-pi3, yocto, bitbake

I am trying create a basic linux image with OpenGL support for a rpi3. I have succesfully created a bootable image and the sdk, but it doesn't contains OpenGL.

I have run

```
bitbake core-image-base
```

with the following changes/additions `conf/local.conf` without success.

```
MACHINE ??= "raspberrypi3
...
IMAGE_FEATURES += "ssh-server-dropbear"
MACHINE_FEATURES_append=" vc4graphics"
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " opengl"
```

It correctly adds the ssh server, but when I log into the flashed rpi, I can't find any opengl libraries.

What is the correct way to add OpenGL to the image?

Comment: You have a space before opengl in DISTRO_FEATURES. Try DISTRO_FEATURES_append = "opengl", without space